# Открыть проводник и выделить несколько файлов/директорий

Tags: windows, cmd, командная-строка, explorer

У приложения «Проводник» в Windows есть параметр `/select`:

```
explorer /select, C:\AMD
```

Выполнение этой команды приведет к открытию «Проводника», в котором будет выделена указанная директория `C:\AMD`. Можно ли как-либо образом запустить «Проводник» и выделить несколько файлов/директорий?

Comment: Пишем в гугле "explorer командная строка". Открываем первую ссылку http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1022848/36/Karp_-_Hitrosti_Windows_7._Dlya_professionalov.html там есть примеры.

Comment: @nick_n_a я видел эту тему, но не всеравно не нашел там нужного

Comment: Да правда нету, к тому же microsoft официальную доку - тоже не получается найти.

Comment: Задача решаема с помощью [VBscript](https://superuser.com/questions/1230810/vbs-select-one-file-in-a-folder). При желаниии скрипт можно впихнуть в батник и выполнить.

Comment: @Daemon-5 можно по подробнее? Желательно ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHS-скрипт стартует Проводник, открывая папку указанную 0-ым параметром.
А затем выделяет файл, указанный 1-ым параметром (1.txt), и 2-ым - второй файл (2.txt).

Исходный код взят с [SuperUsers](https://superuser.com/questions/1230810/vbs-select-one-file-in-a-folder). Проверки на доступ к каталогам и файлам, ровно как и проверки на существование файлов не включены в скрипт.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("""" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """")
WScript.Sleep 400

Set objShellAPP = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
With objShellAPP.Windows(objShellAPP.Windows.Count - 1).document
.SelectItem .Folder.Items.Item(WScript.Arguments(1)), 17
.SelectItem .Folder.Items.Item(WScript.Arguments(2)), 17
End With
```

Соответственно, данный скрипт запускается так:

**cscript //nologo my_script.vbs c:\AMD 1.txt 2.txt**

или

**wscript //nologo my_script.vbs c:\AMD 1.txt 2.txt**

P.S. Примеров упаковки VBscript-файла в тело bat-файла вполне достаточно, чтобы сделать это самостоятельно. Как правило, это вывод скрипта во временный файл и его вызов.

Comment: а можно ли как-то запускать не с папки юзера?

Comment: Работа данного скрипта не зависит от рабочего каталога, т.е. от пути, откуда он был запущен. Важны лишь входные параметры: имя открываемого каталога и имена выделяемых файлов

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно сделать из командной строки, команда `/select` принимает только один параметр. Программными средствами это можно сделать, используя функцию WinAPI [`SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shopenfolderandselectitems).

*<sub>Смотрите аналогичный [вопрос](https://superuser.com/questions/202449/explorer-exe-command-line-options-selecting-multiple-files) на SuperUser.</sub>*